Diverging integrals and bounds
My analysis is quite rusty, so I am looking for some help with the following:
Suppose we have a function which diverges (logarithmically) at $x = 0$, e.g. $f(x) =\frac{1}{x}$. If we then want to integrate this function where the integration bounds are equal, I would write this as
$$\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0} \int_{-\epsilon}^{\epsilon}\frac{1}{x}dx.$$
To me it seems like this should be zero, but I fail to prove this, let alone for a function more complicated than $f(x) =\frac{1}{x}$.
I am aware this might be a weird question, but this problem is related to a physics question I am solving.
Edit: The question I have is based on this, more specifically eq. (3.56- 3.58), where the denominator $\mathcal{R}$ blows up with a double root ($\mathcal{R}(r) = \mathcal{R}'(r) = 0$). The idea is then to look at precisely these $r$ values and see if the definition of these integrals (improper or not) still make sense. To me it seems that these integrals simply are zero because the bounds are equal, but I'd like to be certain.

This might help : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value#Examples

and more generally distribution theory

From this I get that my integral for $1/x$ equals zero. But is this the same as saying it is just a consequence of the bounds being equal regardless of whether the integrand diverges?

In the Cauchy principal value we are excluding the $0$ value.

@RaymondManzoni But that's precisely what my question is about though...

In (advanced) physics you'll find things (for $f$ an odd function and say $b>a>0$) like $PV \int_{-a}^{b} f(x) dx= \int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx$ and $PV \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x),dx=0$ : the point is to remove the singular parts at $0$ and infinity. This is generalized in distribution theory where you'll encounter the neat Dirac $\delta$ distribution to better handle the singular parts.

Even when the bounds are symmetric $\int\limits_{-a}^a\dots$, the limiting expression is of the form $\lim_{\epsilon_1\to -a}\lim_{\epsilon_2\to a}\int\limits_{\epsilon_1}^{\epsilon_2}\dots$, where to be defined in the sense of Riemann the result should be independant of how the limits are taken. The Cauchy PV corresponds to the choice of taking the symmetric limit around the problematic point $\lim_{\epsilon\to a}\int\limits_{-\epsilon}^\epsilon \dots$

@Sal so this means that it's zero no?

Your impulse is certainly in the right ballpark, but has a few things reversed... easy-enough to do.
I'd wager that in whatever context you are, what you really have is something like the principal-value integral/functional,
$$
\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+}\int_{|x|\ge \varepsilon} {f(x)\over x}\;dx
$$
That is, there's some $f$ that makes the thing converge at infinity, or maybe the integral is not trying to be over the whole real line, but just over some finite interval... and then the issue is how to deal with the blow-up at $0$.
As in comments (and "definitions" of "improper integrals"), if we let the bounds approach $0$ independently, there'll be no limit. Harnessing the two limit-approaches together does/can produce something well-defined (and finite!).
In the end, we should realize that such principal value integrals are not literal integrals any more. They are certainly well-defined functionals/distributions (on certain spaces of functions), and are obviously siblings of literal integrals, but are in a slightly larger world. :)
EDIT: in response to the questioner's comment: yes,
$$
\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+} PV\int_{-\varepsilon}^\varepsilon {dx\over x} = 0
$$
where, for each $\varepsilon$ in the outer limit, $PV$ is the principal value
$$
\lim_{\delta\to 0^+}\int_{\delta\le|x|\le \varepsilon}{dx\over x}
$$
For every $\varepsilon>0$ and $\delta>0$, that inner integral is $0$, because $1/x$ is an odd function, yes. But it is dangerous to be too glib about the details. :)

Thanks for the answer! I updated my question with some more info on the integral I'm referring to.  But if I understand correctly, this means that by taking the limit approaching the bounds in a nice way, this should give $0$ (or at least should be well-defined) in my $1/x$ example above?

Thank you for updating! However, it now seems that the clue has to do with $1/x$ being odd (around the pole). What can we say if the function is even (around the pole)? I'm getting from this that it matters if the function goes to $+\infty$ or $-\infty$...

Well, yeah, the PV will not be zero for a not-odd function...

Thanks! I'm not yet entirely up to speed with everything, but I think I can go further with this. If I have any more questions, I'll post them here :)

@Geigercounter :)
